# VSCode Asciidoctor snippet and word suggestions not working despite being enabled

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, asciidoc, asciidoctor

Dear Fellow Asciidoc/VSCode users!

I've recently switched to Windows from Linux. It is true I have not updated my Linux VSCode or any extensions for a few years now, because it worked as I wanted and didn't want any new features to brick anything. So, my issue might not be os-release-related, but rather version-related.

In .adoc files, I cannot seem to be able to enable word/snippet suggestions. Some code suggestions work, but not my snippets and simple text suggestions from one or more currently opened files. This worked on my old setup.

Enabling suggestions with `editor.wordBasedSuggestions`, `editor.suggest.showWords: true`, `editor.snippetSuggestions`, or the other related settings options I was able to find does nothing, even after reloading the editor.
Suggestions work normally in .txt and .py files for example.

While I didn't find anything online on how to enable suggestions, I did find a lot of posts where people wanted to disable word suggesting and also failing to do so using the above-noted settings options.

I must be missing something. Could it be a language-configuration issue? I couldn't find any relevant settings here: [Language Configuration Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide).
Could it be related to something else in the [AsciiDoc](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=asciidoctor.asciidoctor-vscode) language extension?

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.